# How would I style my input element in css?

Tags: html, css, input

```
  <form class="shopify" action="" method="get">
                    <input type="image" src="images/shopify.png" style="width:15%;   border: 5px solid #95bf47; border-radius: 5px; ">

                  </form>
```

This is what I'm doing right now but I want to address it in my css file rather than using `style=""`. I've tried everything I can think of. I have 2 elements like this that need different styling so doing `input{}` will not work in this case. Anyone got a solution? Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors

Comment: Yeah this doesn't help me I have two separate elements that need different styling. By addressing all inputs I can't give each element their own style

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the rest of the selectors and see which are suitable. (This really is CSS 101 and covered by any introductory tutorial, you shouldn't need to resort to Stackoverflow for something like this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can either give an `id` to your input by using attribute `id="input-id"` and then, in css write:

```
#input-id {
...
}
```

or, if you have several input, give a class to your input by writing `class="input-class"` and in your css:

```
.input-class {
...
}
```

Finally, if you want to format all inputs, you can just write in your css:

```
input {
...
}
```

Is it what you were searching for?

Comment: It's been a long day. I missed the obvious *facepalm* Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you have tried? I don't exactly understand where is the issue.

Just add class to it and in your css file:

```
.myInput {
    width:15%;
    border: 5px solid #95bf47;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: It's been a long day. I missed the obvious *facepalm* Thank you!